# Xdebug not listening on port (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, iis, xdebug

I installed Xdebug on my Windows 2019 Server as described on the documentation. But the server is not listening on the given port.
My php.ini settings:

```ini
[xDebug]
zend_extension="C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = x.x.x.x
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.mode = trace, debug
xdebug.collect_assignments = true
xdebug.collect_return = true
xdebug.log = "C:\inetpub\logs\xDebug.log"
xdebug.log_level = 7
xdebug.output_dir = "C:\inetpub\logs\xDebug"
xdebug.trace_output_name = trace.%H
```

But if I check with `netstat -aon`, the server is not listening on the port `9003`. No matter what port number I add. The installation is a fresh Windows Server 2019 with IIS and PHP configured.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>php -v
PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2021 14:12:27) ( NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

In the log file, I get only:

```
[2236] Log opened at 2021-08-05 08:38:25.637570
[2236] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: x.x.x.x:9003.
[2236] [Step Debug] ERR: Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 10.233.233.2:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[2236] Log closed at 2021-08-05 08:38:25.864249
```

The trace is working fine.

It also doesn't work on my Windows 10 21H1 machine. The same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I check with `netstat -aon`, the server is not listening on the port 9003

That is correct, because it is the **IDE** that needs to listen for incoming connections **from** Xdebug. It is the latter that connects to the IDE.

This is also in the documentation: https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#configure:

> …you need to tell Xdebug where to make the debugging connection to, as
> it is Xdebug that initiates the communication to the IDE, and not the
> other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
The issue was the windows firewall. I allowed connection on port tcp/9003 and set to log droped connection. In the log was no droped connection. So I truested that log :-(
I enabled all connection from the IP and now it is working like a charme.

Answer (score 1):

By configuring client_host and client_port you tell xDebug where to connect. And then you should listen for incoming connections, for example, in your IDE. If you want to debug code on a remote server, and use PhpStorm locally, you may need to setup ssh tunnel to allow remote xdebug connect to your local machine. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html#debug-php-cli-scripts-with-remote-php-interpreters-or-via-ssh-tunnel